# Cordova inappbrowser system option

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

What I want to do is open a webpage, using the system browser, but have it display inside the cordova app wrapper, and not pop out and load in the browser. But I want to be able to use the system browser as this is the only control that will allow the camera as an option on a web page with a HTML file input control. The _blank and _self options open and the file input control only takes you to the devices gallery.
Any ideas greatly appreciated.
I need to use it this way so I can call a web page already in existence but display it as an app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take picture from the camera and upload it to your server from your app use `cordova-plugin-camera`. InAppBrowser is a wrong way.

Comment: Hi. Thanks but please re read the question that's not what I'm trying to achieve.